# Communication between Chromium (raspberryPi) and chrome on windows

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I started creating some chrome extensions a while ago and since I am new to JS in general, I need advice with this problem.

**Scenario:**
Chromium is running an extension on a raspberryPi 2. It's "crawling" a website, collecting information in a giant object. Converted to JSON, it consists of around 80.000 characters. This happens every 30 minutes. I am using a raspberry to keep the database up to date 24/7. There is no API for the website.

On my Windows 10 pc, there is another chrome extension, which is used to enhance the experience on a website by comparing values from there to values from the object (extracted by the raspberry).

I am trying to build up a connection between the raspberry pi and my pc to share the database.

**I tried:**

If I run the "crawler" on the same pc as the "enhancing" extension, I am able to store and get the object this way, which works perfectly fine:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('items', function(data) {

    database = JSON.parse(data.items);

});
```

chrome.storage.sync does not work because the object / JSON is too long.

I never (successfully) managed to communicate between my webserver and an extension, because it's mostly limited to communicate between domains.

1) What would be the best way to get the database from the raspberry to my windows pc every time it updates?

2) Shall I send it to a webspace   and then download it with the extension running on windows? How   would I do this with such a big string?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need it to be an _extension_ on the rPi? I mean, I assume rPi is mostly unattended. It would maybe make more sense to use something like phantom.js (if you want to stick with JS) to run your scraping + expose a webserver that your extension can query.

Comment: Someone already suggested something like this (NightmareJS was the name I think). No, It doesnt need to be a extension. It's just that I started coding with chrome extensions and it's the only thing I can do so far. Are things like phantomJS hard to use and setup if I have only basic JS knowledge?

Comment: NightmareJS automates a browser. PhantomJS is headless: there is a browser engine, but no UI. Therefore, it's likely to be better for an unattended device, no need to run a graphics shell just for that.

Comment: _"Are things like phantomJS hard to use and setup if I have only basic JS knowledge?"_ I wouldn't know as I haven't used it myself. But at least it's still JS.

Comment: Okay. Will look into this. The extension is clicking some buttons on that website to get to the needed information, so there is actually a little automation needed. If I'd use phantom, would this make my problem about sharing information between too and windows PC easier or was phantom just a tip In general? Thanks already for your help! - oh well. Overread the thing about the webserver in the first comment. Sorry.